# Using @ManyToOne value in Thymeleaf template - property '' is not readable or has an invalid getter method Does the return type of the getter

Tags: java, spring, jpa, thymeleaf

I've been struggling for hours and I guess it's simple but I'm missing something

I use Thymeleaf as a template engine and in a ManyToOne relationship what is working fine for a class and values doesn't work in other files (other classes, other relationships, same method)

I always get :
Bean property 'Client' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

Many thanks for your help :

in a class Implantation i have this :

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="client_id")
private Client clients;

public Client getClients() {
    return clients;
}
public void setClients(Client clients) {
    this.clients = clients;
}
```

on the other side the class Client

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "clients")
private List<Implantation> implantations;
```

in the template

```
<div class="input-group"> 
        <select class="form-control " th:field="*{Client}" id="dropDownClientId" >
        <option th:each="idclient : ${recupClientID}" th:value="${idclient.getId()}" 
th:text="${recupClientID.getId()}"></option>
        </select>
</div>
```

the controller :

```
   @RequestMapping("updateImplantation/{id}")
public String updateImplantation(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id, ModelMap modelMap) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = auth.getName();
    Iterable<Implantation> listImplantations = implantationService.getAllImplantations();
    Implantation implantationId = implantationService.get(id);
    modelMap.addAttribute("implantation", listImplantations);
    modelMap.addAttribute("implantationId", implantationId);
    modelMap.addAttribute("recupEmail", username);
    return "updateImplantation";
}
```

the "access" of the view is from another one and the edit/update is coming from :

[image: href to access to the problem view]

Comment: Can you add the code of your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my issue
it was not in my mapping but in my controller and the way i used to access

```
@RequestMapping("/editImplantation")
public ModelAndView editImplantationForm(@RequestParam int id) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("updateImplantation");
    Implantation implantation = implantationService.get(id);
    modelAndView.addObject("implantation", implantation);
    return modelAndView;
}

<a th:href="@{/editImplantation(id=${imp.getId()})}">
```

in any case, thank you Wim for your time
as well as to all the others, even those who didn't give an answer or comment